# How can I detect if an element had it's css changed by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

First, let me explain what I am trying to accomplish. I have a line from a poem and you need to click on the word that is "stressed." When you click on a word, jQuery bolds it. I have a submit button and I want something to happen if you have the correct word bolded when the button is clicked. I have tried detecting if the item has focus, or if the item has been clicked, but nothing is working.

```
$("#w4").on(iEng.et('click'),function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });

    $('#w1').on(iEng.et('click'),function() {
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        $('#w2').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w3').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w4').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w5').css("font-weight","normal");
    });



    $('#w2').on(iEng.et('click'),function() {
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        $('#w1').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w3').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w4').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w5').css("font-weight","normal");

    });

    $('#w3').on(iEng.et('click'),function() {
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        $('#w1').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w2').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w4').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w5').css("font-weight","normal");

    });

    $('#w4').on(iEng.et('click'),function() {
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        $('#w1').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w2').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w3').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w5').css("font-weight","normal");

    });



    $('#w5').on(iEng.et('click'),function() {
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
        $('#w1').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w2').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w3').css("font-weight","normal");
        $('#w4').css("font-weight","normal");

    });
```

Also, if it's relevant, I am using a program called Hype to generate the html5 code.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just store a clicked word in `onclick` event handler?

Comment: Would you be able to share your code?

Comment: Not really... All the html 5 code is being generated using a program called Hype. Here is a block of the jQuery I'm using to bold the word when clicked:

$('#w1').on(iEng.et('click'),function() {
 $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
 $('#w2').css("font-weight","normal");
 $('#w3').css("font-weight","normal");
 $('#w4').css("font-weight","normal");
 $('#w5').css("font-weight","normal");
});

Sorry, I don't know how to format code here... and 
If the code looks funny it's because i'm using a custom javascript library, but it's the same as using an onclick event.

Comment: One should edit question to paste in the code. One should use formatting (when editing click help link on the right - it helps).

Comment: i did paste in the code and it's formatted, but when I click add comment the code becomes unformatted.

Comment: @mattrd, your question is updated...

Comment: Is each word wrapped in an element? I'm presuming that your id's with `w{value}` are referencing some sort of element (probably a span) each of which contains one word. Is this correct?

Comment: they are each in a div. named w1 - w5. whenever one is clicked it becomes bold and unbolds any other word that was previously clicked.

Comment: @mattrd Great that helps out a lot. See my answer below with the edit. I think it'll accomplish what you're wanting...

Comment: @war10ck thanks i'll check it out and try to implement it

Answer (score 0):

If the text is bolded, it must be contained in some container element, most likely a `span`. So using JQuery (or just JavaScript), you can look for such elements in your text and check which word is in it.

If you click a word to make it bold, you can then right-click it, and choose 'inspect element' (in most browsers). You can then easily see what kind of element was used.

I've added a snipped that doesn't use ids, but uses classes instead. The advantage is that you can have the same class for multiple elements. That allows you to cut your code dramatically, since you have the same behaviour for all elements. In this case, bolding the clicked word and unbolding the rest is just a couple of lines. You can still use ids if that is convenient for other situations if you need to.

For the check, I get the text of the element that is bold and compare it to the word 'base' in this case. If the word is one of the specific 'are's, this check won't cut it, of course, but I don't know if that applies to your case.

```js
// The logic only applies to elements inside the div 'poem'.
$('.poem')
  
  // Add an on click handler to '.poem', that is triggered when a '.word' inside it is clicked.
  // This allows you to change the words dynamically (as long as you will also add the spans 
  // around it) without having to re-assign the events.
  .on('click', '.word', 
    function(){

      // Remember the state, so you can actually toggle a word on and off.
      // If you don't need that, you can just remove the class from all elements, and
      // then call $(this).addClass('selected');
      var wasSelected = $(this).hasClass('selected');

      $('.word').removeClass('selected');

      $(this).toggleClass('selected', !wasSelected);
    })

  // Event handler like above. Responds to clicks on a button inside '.poem'.
  .on('click', 'button', function(){
      var $words = $('.poem .word.selected');
      if ($words.length == 0) 
      {
        alert('Please select a word');
        return;
      }

      // Get the text of the selected word.
      var selectedText = $words.text();
      if (selectedText == 'base') 
        alert('yay'); 
      else 
        alert('nay');
    });
```

```css
.word.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poem">
<span class="word">roses</span>
<span class="word">are</span>
<span class="word">red</span>,
<span class="word">violets</span>
<span class="word">are</span>
<span class="word">blue</span>,
<span class="word">all</span>
<span class="word">my</span>
<span class="word">base</span>
<span class="word">are</span>
<span class="word">belong</span>
<span class="word">to</span>
<span class="word">you</span>.
<button>check</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It is in a div with the id of "w4". I'm not sure how to use jQuery to look for divs and check which word is in it.

Comment: `$('#w4').text()` will return the text inside that div. But make sure that the id is always w4. If it changes between clicks, it won't work.

Comment: okay, any of the words ("w1","w2","w3","w4","w5") can be bold. "w4" is the one that is supposed to be bolded. How do I check that the right one is bolded when I click submit?

Comment: Can you share some more code? I don't have a clear view on how it works now. Do those divs always exist, or only when you click a word?

Comment: that is all the jQuery(and iEng code) I have right now. Each id is on a div, with text in it.

Comment: I've added a snipped that doesn't use ids, but uses classes instead. The advantage is that you can have the same class for multiple elements. That allows you to cut your code dramatically, since you have the same behaviour for all elements. In this case, bolding the clicked word and unbolding the rest is just a couple of lines. You can still use ids if that is convenient for other situations if you need to.

Comment: For the check, I get the text of the element that is bold and compare it to the word 'base' in this case. If the word is one of the specific 'are's, this check won't cut it, of course, but I don't know if that applies to your case.

Comment: One of the biggest downsides of using hype is you can't give classes to elements. Only ids.

Comment: Really? I don't know hype, so I didn't know. You could give the container the id `#poem`, and alter the jQuery so it searches for `$('#poem div')` to get all the divs in the poem, which should also be all the words. Apart from that, the code can be the same, after all, using jQuery, you can still add classes, I assume.

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol. I got it to be able to identify the correct word when bolded. Unfortunately there are 4 lines to the poem altogether and it needs to know when all the correct words (one for each line) are selected

Comment: No elements around the lines, I presume? A `<P>` perhaps?

Comment: each word is in a div, and all those divs are also in a div

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming each word is wrapped in it's own element (probably a `<span>`) based on your id names above. It would seem that `w{value}` would specify the word number in the poem. Correct me if this is wrong. In that case, your solution should be easy.

As long as your initial styling is in a `<style>` tag or external stylesheet the following solution should work.

When jQuery adds styles to an element, it adds them inline using a `style="..."` attribute. Simply check for this attribute when selecting your bolded element like so:

```
var word = $('div[style]').text();
```

The word with the `style` attribute is the user's choice. Once selected, use `.text()` as demonstrated above to pull the selected word.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment on the other answer, it appears you would to compare the selected word to the correct word in the poem (word 4). For this do the following:

```
if($('div[style]').text() === $('#w4').text()) {
    ... // handle correct response
} else {
    ... // handle error response
}
```

I know this may be a big leap but you could future proof yourself by changing your logic up a little. If there ever came a time when those words might be translated, you could instead base your logic on the element's id value instead like so:

```
if($('div[style]')[0].id = "w4") {
    ... // handle correct response
} else {
    ... // handle error response
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Based on the comment thread below, it appears that the initial inline styles are auto generated and cannot be removed. In order to accomodate for this situation, we can change our selector to search for a specific CSS property (a bit hacky but it works):

Change:

```
$('div[style]')
```

to:

```
$('div[style*="font-weight: bold"]')
```

**References:**

[jQuery Attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: what should be in place of the ('div[style]')? 
Sorry, I'm still really new to a lot of this.

Comment: Oh I got it, that's checking for the style attribute. Right? every word comes up as incorrect... even the correct word. Here is the actual generated code for one of the words.

<div class="HYPE_element" id="w4" hyp_a="0px" hyp_b="359px" style="pointer-events: auto; position: absolute; padding: 8px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); display: inline; font-family: Montserrat; -webkit-user-select: none; font-size: 46px; word-wrap: break-word; cursor: pointer; overflow: visible; white-space: nowrap; z-index: 4; top: 0px; left: 359px;">Great</div>

Comment: @mattrd No worries. There's a small learning curve to it. Nothing should be in place of `div[style]`. `div[style]` will be the one div that jQuery altered. As jQuery cannot touch the contents of stylesheets, it will alter the inline style. Find the inline style and you've found the word.

Comment: @mattrd Ah, yes as noted above, this solution will work if you remove the initial inline styles and instead place them into an external stylesheet (preferred method) or a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of the document. You'll need to make sure none of the word divs have inline styles for this solution to work though.

Comment: crap. Okay, I don't think that's possible at this point.  Because I'm not writing the code and it's all generated, I don't have much control over the attributes and the inline styles. I really appreciate all your help anyways.

Comment: @mattrd The only other thing you could try is to modify the above selector to use the attribute contains selector. It's a little hacky but basically it would be like this `$('div[style*="font-weight: bold"]')` instead of the above `$('div[style]')` selector. Based on your inline styles in the comment above, it doesn't look like there is an initial `font-weight: bold` on any of the word elements. In this way, you can target the one element that has a style tag containing a `font-weight: bold` value in it. This should also filter out the `font-weight: normal` elements. Super hacky but may work

Comment: That worked! Thank you. The actual poem has 4 lines and there is one word that has to be clicked in each line for they submit. But this is enough for me to go on I think. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: shouldn't this code technically work if two correct words are chosen?

    ($('div[style*="font-weight: bold"]').text() === $('#w4').text() && $('div[style*="font-weight: bold"]').text() === $('#w7').text())

Comment: @mattrd Not exactly. Both selectors will pull multiple elements. If you check the `.length` property `$('div[style*="font-weight: bold"]').length` you'll get the total number of matched elements. You'll then need to iterate through these using jQuery's `.each()` method to match each selected match to the correct word.